# Setting label to false in schema not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I'm trying to remove the label in schema. Every time I set it to false it errors or does nothing.

```
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    classifications: {
        type: Schema.Classification,
        optional: true,
        label: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` is a string.  Either set it to a string or omit it from your schema:

```
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    classifications: {
        type: Schema.Classification,
        optional: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeh I want to stop it from printing `classifications` as a label when I access it like `{{> afQuickField name='profile.classifications.classification'}}`

Comment: if you're looking to 'hide' the field in an AutoForm kind of form, then you need to add: `autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }`